# SwiftUI IOS Dynamic CorePlot Data

Tags: core-plot

How do I implement dynamic data to my CorePlot? I'd like my graph to look like this:

[image]

How should I implement my JSON API and to decode the values to set it as X-axis?

JSON API: https://dcmicrogridiep.000webhostapp.com/datamainjson.php

This is my sample code for the CorePlot graph which uses hard coded values.

```
import Foundation
import SwiftUI
import CorePlot

class CalculatePlotData: ObservableObject {
    
    var plotDataModel: PlotDataClass? = nil
    

    func plotYEqualsX()
    {
        
        //set the Plot Parameters
        plotDataModel!.changingPlotParameters.yMax = 10.0
        plotDataModel!.changingPlotParameters.yMin = -5.0
        plotDataModel!.changingPlotParameters.xMax = 10.0
        plotDataModel!.changingPlotParameters.xMin = -5.0
        plotDataModel!.changingPlotParameters.xLabel = "x"
        plotDataModel!.changingPlotParameters.yLabel = "y"
        plotDataModel!.changingPlotParameters.lineColor = .red()
        plotDataModel!.changingPlotParameters.title = " y = x"
        
        plotDataModel!.zeroData()
        var plotData :[plotDataType] =  []
        
        
        for i in 0 ..< 120 {

            //create x values here

            let x = -2.0 + Double(i) * 0.2

        //create y values here

        let y = x * 8


            let dataPoint: plotDataType = [.X: x, .Y: y]
            plotData.append(contentsOf: [dataPoint])
        
        }
        
        plotDataModel!.appendData(dataPoint: plotData)
        
        
    }
    
    
    func ploteToTheMinusX()
    {
        
        //set the Plot Parameters
        plotDataModel!.changingPlotParameters.yMax = 10
        plotDataModel!.changingPlotParameters.yMin = -3.0
        plotDataModel!.changingPlotParameters.xMax = 10.0
        plotDataModel!.changingPlotParameters.xMin = -3.0
        plotDataModel!.changingPlotParameters.xLabel = "x"
        plotDataModel!.changingPlotParameters.yLabel = "y = exp(-x)"
        plotDataModel!.changingPlotParameters.lineColor = .blue()
        plotDataModel!.changingPlotParameters.title = "exp(-x)"

        plotDataModel!.zeroData()
        var plotData :[plotDataType] =  []
        for i in 0 ..< 60 {

            //create x values here

            let x = -8.0 + Double(i) * 5

        //create y values here

        let y = exp(-x)
            
            let dataPoint: plotDataType = [.X: x, .Y: y]
            plotData.append(contentsOf: [dataPoint])
        }
        
        plotDataModel!.appendData(dataPoint: plotData)
        
        return
    }
    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need the actual date values elsewhere in the app, you can just send the numbers in the "times" field provided by the API to the plot directly. You'll set the plot ranges based on those values and define a label formatter with the correct reference date to properly display the date values. Look at the *DatePlot* example app for a simple Swift example.

Comment: Thank you for the recommendation, Do you also have a guide for the implementation and decoding of the values from API for CorePlot integration?

Comment: You have to convert your plot data to `NSNumber` or `double` values depending on which datasource method you decide to implement. How you do that really depends on the format that you receive the data in. In many cases, you won't need to do any conversion at all.